# Auto Mapping Network Drives

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, mappeddrive

I'm an IT Apprentice trying to use a group policy (in Windows Server 2012) to auto map network folders when someone first logs on to a machine. This is the batch file I have written and the '*Share*' folder maps at logon, but the '*personal*' folder doesn't map.

```
NET USE */delete
NET USE C: \\3AAA-LIVERPOOL\Home$\%LogonUser% /PERSISTENT:YES
NET USE C: \\3AAA-LIVERPOOL\Share /PERSISTENT:YES
```

I have manually mapped the folder on the client machine but the GPO won't auto map the file.

**What is the correct code to do this?**

I figured it was an it was an issue with the path but the same path works when manually mapped on the client machine.

Thank you:)

Comment: You're trying to map to a local path rather than a UNC path.

Comment: You should also investigate whether or not folder redirection is an appropriate use for at least the home share https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732275(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: C: is normally where Windows is installed and running. You can't map a network drive to an already existing and used drive letter. Try E: or F: or a different drive letter for the share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First** of all, you are trying to map your shared folder to drive C, which is usually taken by your Windows installation. Instead you want to map it to a free drive letter like M, P, Q, S, … whatever is free.

```
NET USE S: \\3AAA-LIVERPOOL\Share
```

**Secondly**, you are trying to map multiple network shares to a single drive letter. This does not work, only one network share per drive letter is allowed. Aynthing else would not make sense.

```
NET USE H: \\3AAA-LIVERPOOL\Home$\%LogonUser% /PERSISTENT:YES
NET USE S: \\3AAA-LIVERPOOL\Share /PERSISTENT:YES
```

**Third**, `%LogonUser%` does not exist, see `echo %LogonUser%`. You probably want to use `%username%`. (Environmental variables are case-insensitive, btw.)

**Fourth**, there is a better way to configure a home directories for your users documented here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/06/30/automatic-creation-of-user-folders-for-home-roaming-profile-and-redirected-folders/

**Fifth**, there is a better way to map drives other than the home directory, as Slipeer already pointed out. But I'll mention it, too, for the sake of completeness.

**Last**, you are missing a white space in the delete command.

```
NET USE * /delete
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better [use Group Policy Preference to map drives](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770902%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for user.

In your case, the possible cause of the problem:

1. You use one drive name for both shares. It will be mount only last share.
2. Is it *logon* (user policy section) or *startup* (computer policy section) script? Startup scripts are run on the computer account and can not have access to private user share.

Comment: In addition to 2) they consequently don't have an env-var `%username%`.